# Prove that for any $t\ne s$, $P(B_{t}>B_{s})=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes

> A Brownian motion $B_t$ of parameter $\sigma^2$. Prove that for any to $t \neq s$, $P(B_t>B_s)=\frac{1}{2}$.

is: 
$f_{B_t,B_s}(x,y) \Longrightarrow f_{B_t,B_s-B_t}(x,y-x)$
$f_{B_t}(x)f_{B_s-B_t}(y-x) =p(t,o,x)p(t-s,x,y)$

$=\int_A p(t-s,0,u)du $

that's $u=y-x$

$$\int_A p(t-s,0,u) \, du =\int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2} (s-t)}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2 u}} \, du$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2(s-t)}}\int_A e^{-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2 (s-t)} } \, du $$

Being $p^2=\frac{u^{2}}{2\sigma^2 (s-t)}$ so:

$$p=\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2 (s-t)}}\Longrightarrow p=\frac{u}{\sigma}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2(s-t)}}\Longrightarrow  p=\frac{u}{\sigma}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(s-t)}}$$

$$\frac{dp}{du}=\frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(s-t)}}\Longrightarrow \sigma\sqrt{2(s-t)} \, dp=du  $$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2} u}}\int_A e^{-p^2}\sigma\sqrt{2(s-t)} \,  dp $$

$$\frac{\sigma\sqrt{2(s-t)} }{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 (s-t)}} \int_A e^{-p^2} \, dp \Longrightarrow 
\frac{\sigma\sqrt{2(s-t)} }{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 (s-t)}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-p^2} \, dp $$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-p^2}dp $$

So $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-p^2} \, dp=\sqrt{\pi} $

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{\pi}=1 $$

$$\int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 (s-t)}} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2 u}} \, du = 1 $$

> Supposedly must give the value $\frac{1}{2}$, but the integral function of Gauss gives me $\sqrt{\pi}$. I am right?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: The beginning of the question is unclear, and not in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a standard Brownian motion is a continuous adapted process $B = \{B_t, \cal{F}_t; 0\leq t < \infty\}$ defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \cal{F}, P)$ with $B_0 = 0$ a.s. and for $0 \leq s < t$, the increment $B_t - B_s$ is independent of $\cal{F}_s$ and is normally distributed with mean zero and variance $t-s$. (Karatzas and Shreve, Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus, 2e, Definition 2.1.1)

If you have a parameter $\sigma^2$, the variance is $\sigma^2(t-s)$ instead.

So, for $t>s$, $P(B_t>B_s) = P(B_t - B_s> 0) = P(N(0,\sigma^2(t-s)) >0) = 1/2$.
If $t<s$, $P(B_t>B_s) = P(0 > B_s - B_t) = P(0>N(0,\sigma^2(s-t))) = 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much to solve my doubt.
Sorry no more a question that took the two cases, perhaps it is because:   $P(Bt>Bs)+P(Bt<Bs)=1$ . Thank you again

Comment: $P(A) + P(A^C) = 1$ always ($P(B_t=B_s)=0$ for a Brownian motion, so you can ignore $\{B_t = B_s\}$), so this is not the reason. You can combine the cases by noting that negating a zero mean gaussian doesn't change the distribution.